# How to increment some of elements in an array by specific values in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, vectorization, run-length-encoding

Suppose we have an array

```
A = zeros([1,10]);
```

We have several indexes with possible duplicate say:

```
indSeq = [1,1,2,3,4,4,4];
```

How can we increase `A(i)` by the number of `i` in the index sequence i.e. `A(1) = 2, A(2) = 1, A(3) = 1, A(4) = 3`?

The code `A(indSeq) = A(indSeq)+1` does not work.

I know that I can use the following for loop to achieve the goal, but I wonder if there is anyway that we can avoid for-loop? We can assume that the `indSeq` is sorted.

A for-loop solution:

```
for i=1:length(indSeq)
  A(indSeq(i)) = A(indSeq(i))+1;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) for such a label based counting job, like so -

```
accumarray(indSeq(:),1)
```

**Benchmarking**

As suggested in the [`other answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34326784/3293881), you can also use `hist/histc`. Let's benchmark these two for a large datasize. The benchmarking code I used had -

```
%// Create huge random array filled with ints that are duplicated & sorted
maxn = 100000;
N = 10000000;
indSeq = sort(randi(maxn,1,N));

disp('--------------------- With HISTC')
tic,histc(indSeq,unique(indSeq));toc

disp('--------------------- With ACCUMARRAY')
tic,accumarray(indSeq(:),1);toc
```

Runtime output -

```
--------------------- With HISTC
Elapsed time is 1.028165 seconds.
--------------------- With ACCUMARRAY
Elapsed time is 0.220202 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is run-length encoding, and the following code should do the trick for you.

```
A=zeros(1,10);
indSeq = [1,1,2,3,4,4,4,7,1];
indSeq=sort(indSeq); %// if your input is always sorted, you don't need to do this
pos = [1; find(diff(indSeq(:)))+1; numel(indSeq)+1];
A(indSeq(pos(1:end-1)))=diff(pos)
```

which returns

```
A =
     3     1     1     3     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

This algorithm was written by Luis Mendo for MATL.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the number of occurences of unique values of the array. This can be accomplished with:

```
[num, val] = hist(indSeq,unique(indSeq));
```

the output of your example is:

```
num = 2 1 1 3
val = 1 2 3 4
```

so num is the number of times val occurs. i.e. the number 1 occurs 2 times in your example